# How do i display the button at bottom of the screen at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application i am creating linear layout at run time . In this layout i have created a button. What i want is to display this button at the bottom of the screen? I have tried to use the following code:

```
Button btn = new Button(MoodJournal.this);
btn.setGravity(0x50);
```

But it moves the text within the button to the bottom.

Please help me on this

Thanks

Pankaj

Answer (score 2):

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
```

`import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;`

then

```
            LinearLayout rl = new LinearLayout(this);
            LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rl.setLayoutParams(params);

            Button shake = new Button(this);
            shake.setText("Button");
            LayoutParams param1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param1.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM;
            shake.setLayoutParams(param1);

            rl.addView(shake);
            setContentView(rl);
```

Comment: Thanks androider for replying. I wanted to display the button at the bottom of the screen. The code you posted above displays the button at the bottom of the content. For e.g in the following url http://i.imgur.com/zRQR9.jpg i want to display the button like right side of the image.